# Spring is giving handleHttpMessageNotReadableexception to ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to send three arrays using ajax to controller. My jquery code is:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#sub" ).on('click',function( event ) {
      var first = [];
      var second = [];
      var third = [];
      var k = "<c:out value='${k}'/>";
      alert("k: " + k);
     // var id = "<c:out value='${m}'/>";
     // var d = id.val();
      var id = 1;
      alert("d : " + id);
      var v = 0;
      var y = 0;
      var u = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < k; i++){
          v = $('#s' + i).val();
          y = $('#e' + i).val();
          u = $('#h' + i).val();
          if((v != "undefined") && (v != null)){
              first.push(v);              
          }
          if((y != "undefined") && (y != null)){
              second.push(y);             
          }
         if((u != "undefined") && (u != null)){
              third.push(u);             
          }

      }
      $.ajax({          
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/timeEntry?id=d",
            data : {            
                myData: {
                   "a1": JSON.stringify(first),
                   "a2": JSON.stringify(second),
                   "a3": JSON.stringify(third)                
                }            
            },
            success : function(response) {
                $('.timepicker').timepicker();
            },
            error : function(e) {
               alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        }); 

      event.preventDefault();
    });


});
</script>
```

In my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/timeEntry", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     @ResponseBody
     public String getTimeData(@RequestBody TimeData myData, 
                               @RequestParam(value = "id") String id ){
         System.out.println("Enter time");
         System.out.println(myData.getA1());
         String str = "{\"a\":1, \"b\":\"foo\"}";
         return str;
     }
```

My POJO class is:

```
import java.util.List;

public class TimeData { 

    private List<String> a1;
    private List<String> a2;
    private List<String> a3;

    public TimeData(){

    }



    public TimeData(List<String> a1, List<String> a2, List<String> a3) {        
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
    }



    public List<String> getA1() {
        return a1;
    }
    public void setA1(List<String> a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }
    public List<String> getA2() {
        return a2;
    }
    public void setA2(List<String> a2) {
        this.a2 = a2;
    }
    public List<String> getA3() {
        return a3;
    }
    public void setA3(List<String> a3) {
        this.a3 = a3;
    }   


}
```

But whenever I am trying to send the data, I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpMessageNotReadable
WARNING: Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@68f7b000; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@68f7b000; line: 1, column: 2]
Jan 15, 2016 1:17:46 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@68f7b000; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@68f7b000; line: 1, column: 2]
```

I am new to ajax. Can somebody please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.neiu.scheduler</groupId>
  <artifactId>scheduler</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Also the scheduler-servlet.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="scheduler.controllers"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/staticResources/"
        mapping="/resources/**">
    </mvc:resources>
</beans>
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>The Scheduler</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>scheduler</display-name>
    <servlet-name>scheduler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>scheduler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <description>MySQL Test App</description>
  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/scheduler</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
           classpath:scheduler/config/dao-context.xml 
           classpath:scheduler/config/service-context.xml

        </param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: isn't `k` a string?  How does that work in the for loop? `for(var i = 0; i < k; i++){`...  What is `k` ??

Comment: @zipzit Probably, I used it to assign dynamic ids to my jsp page. But the loop is working since I checked it before to display the values before pushing those into the respective arrays.

Comment: So is `k` a string or an int?  Please `console.log(k + 100);`  Did you get a real sum or a string concatenation?  What do you see when you `console.log(JSON.stringify(first));` from just before the jquery ajax call function?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is the ajax request is malformed in the origin, and fails to populate the TimeData class on the server.  Its not clear the k value is exactly what you intended.  I don't understand the line `var k = "<c:out value='${k}'/>";`  I'm guessing the intent is that would be something served up in Java, but I'm not familiar with that format.  Its also not clear if that value is a numeric or a string.  What is the response to `console.log(k + 100);` ??  Are the numbers summed or are they concatenated?

Additionally the JSON.stringify is possibly leading you astray.  I'd love to see the response `console.log(JSON.stringify(first));` if placed immediately before the jQuery ajax call.  And then in the controller, a  `System.out.println(...);` verification of the data coming in from the Ajax call.  Its not at all clear to me on how that TimeData constructor is getting the data it needs.

Update:  Reminder, in the [jquery Ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) data must be of Type: PlainObject or String or Array.  Check the details of [PlainObject.](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) It doesn't specifically require simple objects, but does give a test to validate.  Your data object is pretty complex.  Can you run a `jQuery.isPlainObject(data);` test in the error portion of your JavaScript call?

Comment: You are right that k is a string. But even after I parsed it into integer, I am still having the problem. I did the two console.log as you suggested just before the ajax call, and it's giving me the correct answer. 104 Times:110:4
Array [ "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM" ] But the system.out.println in the controller is not printing anything since the request is not going inside the controller. Please help....

Comment: Are you seeing an error on the chrome browser console after the ajax call, or is the system going to JS timepicker() ?  (hint: add a `console.log` msg for each success and error?) is the data leaving the browser in EXACTLY the expected format? `console.log(data);` would really help.  Can I see that output copied from Chrome dev tools?

Comment: This is what I got after console.log(myData) before the ajax call: Object {a1: "["1:30 PM","1:30 PM","1:30 PM"]", a2: "["1:30 PM","1:30 PM","1:30 PM"]", a3: "["18","18","18"]"} This is the error I am getting in chrome browser console: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.…line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.26</h3></body></html>", status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request"}

Comment: close.  I said `console.log(data)` Its better to edit your original problem with these responses, it makes things much easier to read.

Comment: Where do you want me to place the console.log(data)? Sorry, I am not very familiar with ajax.

Comment: add `console.log(data); jQuery.isPlainObject(data);` in the error function(e){} area of your ajax call.

Comment: It says: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Profuse apologies.  My bad.  You've already displayed `myData`.  What is result for `jQuery.isPlainObject(myData);`  Ouch.  I'm an idiot. I just read your response message again.  The issue isn't in the client, its on your server.

Comment: jquery.isPlainObject(myData) is giving true.